# RealmSwift replacement for RLMobject

Tags: swift, realm

Whats the correct way todo this with RealmSwift, it used to be RLMobject

```
var stream:Results<streams>
stream = Realm().objects(streams)
```

this first one lives on my class as a global the second line in my viewdidload

this is what i try todo: https://dpaste.de/AKKJ
class tabelviewcontroller has no initializers

the model

```
class streams: Object {
    dynamic var br = ""
    dynamic var categorie = 0
    dynamic var ct = ""
    dynamic var lc = ""
    dynamic var ml = ""
    dynamic var mt = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var shoutcatid = 0
    dynamic var stationid = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "stationid"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, is stream a relationship to another object? What is the full model class, and what are you trying to get back?

Comment: var stream:Results<streams>  (the global object that will hold all results from stream = Realm().objects(streams) wich is called later in a function on the model

Comment: streams is the model

Answer (score 0):

A few quick notes, its good to keep class names singular, my model would look like this:

```
class Stream: Object {
    ...
}
```

If you want to get all objects from streams you can just do this:

```
let results = Realm().objects(Stream)
```

Comment: yeah i just want to put it in a global variable on the class itself

Comment: this first one lives on my class as a global the second line in my viewdidload. Is this within your viewDidLoad? for example
override func viewDidLoad() { .... let results = Realm()... }

Answer (score 0):

```
var stream:Results<streams>!
```

solved it